# Copy rows from and within same oracle SQL table and changing some column values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a table called **table1** within oracle DB that looks like this:

```
ID  USERID  FRUIT   COLOR
1   10      APPLE   BLUE
2   10      ORANGE  RED
3   20      BANANA  YELLOW
```

I would like to build a query that would:
- select all rows from userID 10 and copy them over to the same table, keeping all fields untouched apart from ID (I would guess it should automatically increment itself?). Edit: The increment part will increment itself as long as it is DB column (not user created).

So the result I would like to have is for userID 20 to have userID 10 rows as per below:

```
ID  USERID  FRUIT   COLOR
1   10      APPLE   BLUE
2   10      ORANGE  RED
3   20      BANANA  YELLOW
4   20      APPLE   BLUE
5   20      ORANGE  RED
```

Below is my trial query - will it work?

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE USERID=10;
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle version 10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List the columns and values that you want:

```
INSERT INTO table1(USERID, FRUIT, COLOR)
    SELECT 20, FRUIT, COLOR
    FROM table1
    WHERE USERID = 10;
```

If the `id` is not generated automatically on insert, you can calculate the value:

```
INSERT INTO table1(ID, USERID, FRUIT, COLOR)
    SELECT tt1.maxid + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) as ID,
           20, FRUIT, COLOR
    FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(ID) as maxid FROM table1) tt1
    WHERE USERID = 10;
```

Comment: Can I do `INSERT INTO table1(*)?`

Comment: And will the ID auto increase?

Comment: @lovemyjob - If you're going to populate ***all*** the columns, and won't be making use of defaults or `IDENTITY`, etc, just leave the `(a, b,c)` out...  `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT .......`.  This has a significant weakness though; if the table structure changes (columns moved, or added) it won't necessarily do what you want.  Specifying the columns is strongly recommended.

Comment: @lovemyjob - That depends on the table definition.  Is the `id` column defined as `IDENTITY`?  Is there a trigger to automatically populate it from a sequence?  Or are you responsible for managing the id yourself?  *(We can't answer that for you, you have to investigate your setup...)*

Comment: I investigated the setup, ID (increasing number) is being created automatically, when the end user creates a new row in database. So question is - will the ID increase when I use INSERT query? Or shall I play safe and increment it myself to prevent having same ID values in one table?

Comment: @ilovemyjob - you just said the ID is generated automatically on insert, so yes it will be generated automatically on insert.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence for the `ID` column:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table1__id__seq;
```

and use that for all your inserts.

Then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO table1( id, userid, fruit, color )
  SELECT table1__id__seq.NEXTVAL,
         20,
         fruit,
         color
  FROM   table1
  WHERE  userid = 10;
```